# Angular back button triggering the previous route

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm facing an issue, I have an angular 14 application which when loads displays the modal popup with route

```
http://localhost:4200/select-role
```

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(AppConstants.SCREEN_ROUTES.HOME).then(success => this.loaderService.hide()).catch(err => this.loaderService.hide());
```

Its just an popup with list of roles and radio buttons so user selects one click proceed and lands on landing page with route

```
http://localhost:4200/home
```

Now my this route is constant since we have configured `skipLocation` false. so my entire app has this route(90%).
So from the home there is a link (/steppers) where I navigate to some steppers component and show list of steppers though URL is same `http://localhost:4200/home`  and when I use browser back button it loads `http://localhost:4200/select-role` this pops back again.

How can i restrict it. so when the user click browser back from stepper component, send it back to the home component and not on modal popup.

Comment: you can not restrict that, but you can use Location's onUrlChange method to listen then change in routing and navigate to home component based on your condition.

Comment: you can hostbind the back button and when it is clicked redirect to page you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a static popup which can be visited anytime by clicking on a link/ button, better inject the modal directly in the parent component.

Incase you want to go through the routing approach, I would recommend using [canActivateFn](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivateFn) This way you won't be doing anything custom and leveraging the Angular features to achieve it. All you need to do is to check the previous route from which the page is being navigated and activate the route accordingly, else navigate to '/home'.

Comment: Yes I was able to achieve using `CanActivate`  route guard. Thanks :)